# Updating Record with Approval Step Assignee

Tags: approval-process

I am using an approval process on a change request object. In one of my steps I would like for the Approver of the next step to be chosen by the current Approver. Is there a way to make the Owner of the change request to be made the person who is has been chosen to approve the next step ?

I thought maybe it would have to be done w/ the Approval Process object - but I don't see "Assignee" to be available in the Approval Process, so I wouldn't be able to assign the Owner as the user chosen and assigned as the approver of a step.